# Declaration of function prototypes within classes in C++?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, c++17, prototype

So I've been trying to learn C++ and get familiar with its syntax, but I'm a bit confused in a video I came across that involves some discussion about classes and constructors. Now, I know that we need to provide prototypes of a function if it's used before its declared.

Now I was watching this video, and the code of the video is given below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_b7odUc7lg0

Here, I use `setName(z)` in line 8, inside the constructor. But, `setName()` is only declared in line 10, so why does this piece of code work, without including any prototyping for the `setName()` function declared within the `BuckysClass` class?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class BuckysClass {
public:
    BuckysClass(string z) {
        setName(z);
    }
    void setName(string x) {
        name = x;
    }
    string getName() {
        return name;
    }
private:
    string name;
};


int main()
{
    BuckysClass bo("Lucky Bucky Roberts");
    cout << bo.getName();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can do this with classes and structs. The declaration of the member function does not need to be above use its use in the class declaration

Comment: It works differently for class member functions and free functions. While you can't use free function where it's not declared, you can use class members and member functions in other member functions if they are declared somewhere below. I guess the class definition is parsed two times or something...

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923533/why-doesnt-the-order-of-methods-in-a-class-matter-in-c and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924047/parsing-declarations-before-definitions-in-a-class

Comment: "prototype" is a C term. You probably shouldn't be learning C++ from sources that mix C and C++. This is just one example why.