# According to my interpretation of §3.4.1/8 this code should compile. What am I missing?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14

According to [basic.lookup.unqual]/8 from [N4140](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4140.pdf) the following snippet should compile. But it doesn't in [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03c6d030f364bf92), gcc and vs2013.

```
struct C {
    void f(I) {}
    using I = int;
};
```

[basic.lookup.unqual]/8 (emphases are mine):

> For the members of a class `X`, a name used in a member function body,
>   in a default argument, in an *exception-specification*, in the
>   *brace-or-equal-initializer* of a non-static data member (9.2), or in the definition of a class member outside of the definition of `X`,
>   following the member’s ***declarator-id*<sup>31</sup>**, shall be
>   declared in one of the following ways:
>
> - before its use in the block in which it is used or in an enclosing block (6.3), or
> - **shall be a member of class `X`** or be a member of a base class of `X` (10.2), or
> - ...
>
> **<sup>31) That is, an unqualified name that occurs, for instance, in a type in the *parameter-declaration-clause* or in the
>   *exceptions-pecification*.</sup>**

Comment: Looks to me like `a name used in a member function body, in a default argument, in an exception-specification, in the brace-or-equal-initializer of a non-static data member (9.2), or in the definition of a class member outside of the definition of X` doesn't apply to `I`. It's not in the function body, it's an argument, but not a default one, it has nothing to do with exceptions or initialisation, and it's not outside the definition of `X`...

Comment: The name simply isn't in scope, so you can't refer to it in the member function declarator. The quoted text doesn't change that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way you are using it does not fall under any of the conditions in *[basic.lookup.unqual]/8*, it is not used:

- in a member function body
- in a default argument
- in an exception-specification
- in the brace-or-equal-initializer of a non-static data member

and it does not fall under this case either:

> definition of a class member outside of the definition of X

the following example shows some cases that do follow those rules:

```
struct C {
    int y = I() ;           // brace-or-equal-initializer of non-static data member
    void f(int x = I())     // default argument
      noexcept(sizeof(I)<4) // exception-specification
    {
          I i = x ;         // member function body
    }
    using I = int;   
};
```

Comment: What about the footnote 31?

Comment: Footnotes are not normative.

Comment: @JonathanWakely That isn't even relevant, as the text that the footnote corresponds to is not applying here.

Comment: Footnote 31 just makes it clear that "following the member’s declarator-id" means it applies only to names used in parameters or noexcept clauses. It essentially rules out return values which come before the declarator-id.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Footnote 31 says clearly `name that occurs, for instance, in a **type** in the *parameter-declaration-clause*`

Comment: I'm convinced. You're right. The footnote refers only to a class member defined outside of the class. (+1)

Answer (score 5):

> […] or in the definition of a class member **outside of the definition**
>   of `X`, following the member’s *declarator-id*

I.e. the following is valid

```
struct C {
    using I = int;
    void f(I);
};

void C::f(I) {}
```

Comment: Your snippet should be equivalent to mine. AFAICT, this paragraph basically says that a member-function is always parsed after its class definition, even when defined inline.

Comment: Which part of it says that? The bit that Columbo quoted essentially says that one of the things this rule applies to is to out-of-class definitions. Where do you read that all member definitions are out-of-class?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10923569/1042389) by James McNellis

Comment: I'm convinced, specially because this snippet doesn't (and couldn't) compile: `struct C{ void f(I); using I = int; }; void C::f(I) {}`. (+1)